# Apache reverse proxy keeps demanding basic auth credentials

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I'm configuring Apache in front of [Hawtio](http://hawt.io/) - a Karaf-hosted JVM management console.  Although Hawtio is served by Jetty and protected by Karaf's JAAS implementation, we want Apache to add Basic Auth that we can then additionally secure it - e.g. from brute force attacks with Fail2Ban.

However, despite following advice such as [this](http://www.webreference.com/programming/apache_authentication/index.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972127/how-can-i-protect-a-tomcat-webapp-thats-reverse-proxied-in-an-apache2-virtual-h), Apache's basic auth keeps popping up rather than asking for the credentials once only.  Hawtio's log-in page loads after two requests for credentials but then, once you've put in the Hawtio log-in details, Apache keeps popping up its log-in page. I've even gone as far as entering the credentials twenty times but it still asks for more!

Am I missing something obvious?

Here's my config:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@localhost
  ServerName hawtio.mydomain.com

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  # suppress rule checking for Hawtio stuff
  SecRuleRemoveById 950901 960010 970003 970014 981257 981318 981407 981205 981222 981240 981220

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://application-server:8765/
    ProxyPassReverse http://application-server:8765

    AuthUserFile /etc/users
    AuthName "Restricted area"
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user

    RequestHeader unset Authorization
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried numerous variations including with the `<Proxy>` group rather than `<Location />` but to no avail.  As per [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/238352/apache2-reverse-proxy-with-authentication-on-windows-7), I added `RequestHeader unset Authorization`  to see if it was Jetty that was complaining but neither the presence nor the absence of that directive makes a difference.

The site works perfectly if I remove the basic auth directives.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Is it sending a new 401 to the client each time?  Is the client sending the credentials in each request's headers?

Comment: Hi Shane - thanks for the reply. I've put Wireshark on it, and in the detail it shows a 401 being demanded and the credentials then being passed back to the server once I've typed them in. NB the client in this case is Google Chrome. J.

Comment: PS. sorry, to be clear, it's demanding a 401 multiple times.

Comment: Are the subsequent 401s on the request for the same resource?  In other words, is it `GET /` -> `401` -> `GET /` with authorization -> `401` -> `GET /` with authorization again -> `200`?  Or are the subsequent 401s occurring on requests for other resources?

Comment: Hi Shane - each request is for a different resource.  Is my expectation that one authorisation will cover all matching resources incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried to move proxy out of `<Location />`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a cookie or cache the credentials some how. I've seen this when configuring Apache with one-time passcodes.  mod_auth_radius supports AuthRadiusCookieValid. Not sure what you would use here.

Comment: Thanks - I've come to the conclusion that the basic auth directives are simply not going to work in my case, so I'll bite the bullet and look into certs, RADIUS, etc.